# accidentally deleted my gallery app can you help me

Tags: data-recovery, downloading

i accidentally deleted my gallery app. mine phone is rooted and its micromax a120. so can u help me to recover the app or u can provide me a link so i could download from that link. plz help me. plz

Answer (score 0):

Download your phone's stock gallery app then move it to system/app change the owner

- Owner 0 - root
- Group 1013 - media

Then install apk and restart then you're good to go

Comment: But dude the substitute doesn't have gallery with it n not every camera can do what ur inbuilt camera can do.

Comment: I'm so sorry I tought what you're missing is a camera app. You can do the same method above with a stock or generic gallery app

Comment: Ya but u know why I m asking for that camera n gallery cuz they were best, as far as i m concerned

Comment: you can download any gallery app you like

Comment: Your answer is prone to malfunction, if OP'S SELinux is set on Enforcing. Please perform further research, and add a way to change the new app's context.

Comment: well maybe but this method works for me